# Interact with existing 3D object Unity ARCORE

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm looking for a way to interact with an existing GameObject (as andy in HelloAR).

I saw this post :

[Detecting if an tap event with ARCore hits an already added 3d object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728036/detecting-if-an-tap-event-with-arcore-hits-an-already-added-3d-object)

which partially answers the question, but I'm using the latest release ARCore Developer Preview 2 in Unity in C# not Java.

I'm learning, so I'm not looking for code but more in tutorial or explanation about the User Interact Concept in ARCORE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touching 3D objects is nothing you solve using ARCore. It's in the responsibility of Unity. Everything you need is covered in this Unity tutorial https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/s/roll-ball-tutorial. It's just touching a 3D object in a Unity scene.

Comment: Ok I will go through it and indicate your response as answer when I find my solution, thanks. I imagined it was more difficult than basic interaction with raycast

Comment: It was easier than expected thanks for your indication